# Can't find library dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

Trying to use [PagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter) in my project. According to my understanding I should have `com.android.support:viewpager` library for this purpose. But my search can't find this library. Why?

[image]

Comment: You probably should include it in `build.gradle` first so it gets downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

-Try adding below dependency in app module build.gradle file.

```
compile com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 //or whatever version you need or have
```

In another layout file, you'll need to declare a ViewPager layout.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager ... ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```